# Laravel Get Distinct / Unique Records of Day, Week, Month, Year

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am working on a simple dashboard using Laravel which tracks mostly visitors info.
I can't able to write laravel query builder or eloquent code to

- Select unique visitors of today
- Select unique visitors of this month
- select unique visitors of this week
- select unique visitors of this year

Here is my DB table columns.
[image]

I'm stuck to get unique data if someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write the raw queries and use these.

Today : `select distinct id, ip_address, browser from table_name where DATE(visited_time) = CURDATE();`

Month : `select distinct id, ip_address, browser from table_name where month(visited_time) = month(NOW()) and year(visited_time) = year(NOW());`

Week  : `select distinct id, ip_address, browser from table_name where week(visited_time) = week(NOW()) and year(visited_time) = year(NOW());`

Year  : `select distinct id, ip_address, browser from table_name where year(visited_time) = year(NOW());`

Comment: Note that functions cannot use indexes so use range comparisons where possible

Comment: @Strawberry hmm I actually didn't know that. Thanks for the info

Comment: Wonderful @bassxzero.
Thank you so much :)